# Filtering javascript object structured by date

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database, filter

I have a Firebase Database that stores registers ordered by date. Each part of date is a key. For example for the date 2017-12-01 the collection is something like this:

```
2017 {
    12 {
        01 {
           ...registers
        },
        02 {
           ...registers
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is an image example]

I think that whoever came up with this structure (was not me) tried to avoid that collections takes a huge dimension and that's great, but:

I have to make a query to filter all results between a date range. Selecting an init date and a finish date you must get all registers stored into.

I wrote something like this:

```
for (let index_year in results) {
            if (parseInt(index_year) >= from_year && parseInt(index_year) <= to_year) {
                for (let index_month in results[index_year]) {
                    if(parseInt(index_month) >= from_month && parseInt(index_month) <= to_month) {
                        for (let index_day in results[index_year][index_month]) {
                            if(parseInt(index_day) >= from_day && parseInt(index_day) <= to_day) {

                                items = results[index_year][index_month][index_day];

                                for (let id in items) {
                                    console.log(items[id])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine while the selected dates are within the same year. But if you choose, for example, a date range like: 2017-12-01 to 2018-01-31 the script doesn't return results at all.

Can you think of a better script to make this query? Did someone ever do something similar?

Comment: Can you share with us a real example of your json ? Also is it sorted ?

Answer (score 0):

You could take the wanted range as array with the proper accessors and map this array with the data. Then delete the holes of the result set.

In this example the range goes from `2017-11-29` to `2017-12-06`, but not all dates are in the object available.

If no date or path to the inner property is available, `undefined` is returned. This requires a filtering after mapping.

`getData` works with hierarchical structure and checks the given properties. If it get a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value it takes an (nearly) empty object for the access, which might return `undefined`, an object or a value.

```js
var data = { 2017: { 11: { 28: { data: '2017-11-28' }, 30: { data: '2017-11-30' } }, 12: { '01': { data: '2017-12-01' }, '03': { data: '2017-12-03' }, '05': { data: '2017-12-01' } } } },
    range = [['2017', '11', '29'], ['2017', '11', '30'], ['2017', '12', '01'], ['2017', '12', '02'], ['2017', '12', '03'], ['2017', '12', '04'], ['2017', '12', '05'], ['2017', '12', '06']],
    getData = (object, path) => path.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object),
    result = range.map(date => getData(data, date)).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice @NinaScholz thank you very much. Now I just have to think how to make the range array generator between two dates.